# How to add @Deprecated to every Class and every Constructor/Method of every class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I have some legacy code and I want to mark all of them and all of their methods `@Deprecated` so that as we go and touch them we can remove these annotations so we can keep track of what has been modernized and what still is *bad*.

I am trying to use the `Structural Search/Replace` and can't seem to get the correct template going.

#### Search Template

```
class $Class$ { 
  $ReturnType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$) { $Stmt$; }
}
```

#### Replace Template

```
@Deprecated
class $Class$ {
  @Deprecated
  $ReturnType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$) { $Stmt$; }
}
```

#### But this removes everything else that is in the class.

```
@Deprecated
class OldAndCrusty {
  @Deprecated
   ( );
}
```

This strips off all the visibility modifiers and final modifiers of all the classes it matches.

### How do I replace these things and leave the rest of the code alone?

Comment: It might be easier to add a `package-info.java` class to all packages and annotate the `package` declaration as `@Deprecated`.

Comment: He's asking how to do it in IntelliJ though that is only obvious from the tags. Learning a editor like vim for a multi module java search and replace task isn't a very wise usage of time...

Comment: Doesn't just adding `@Deprecated` to the top level `class $ClassName` statement mark everything in the class?

Comment: regex search and replace won't work in these cases, that is why structual search and replaces exists

Comment: marking the class deprecated only marks that class, the methods don't show up as deprecated unless they have the annotation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't test this as I don't have the proper IntelliJ version. But as I found [here](http://www.onboard.jetbrains.com/articles/04/10/ssr/3.html), you can use a variable for the class content.

Search template:

```
    class $Class$ {
       $MyClassContent$
    }
```

Replacement template:

```
    @Deprecated
    class $Class$ {
       $MyClassContent$
    }
```

The minimum and maximum occurrence counts for the `MyClassContent` variable should be set to `0` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` respectively. This should leave you with the classes annotated.

Now, I suppose you can do the same with a method template too. What I don't know is if you can apply the method template to all methods in the source. That way you should be able do a 2-step search and replace: First for classes, next for methods.

Comment: This is only a partial solution. This only does the class, I want to do all the methods as well in one shot if possible. It also it doesn't work on any non-package level classes or ones that are marked `final`.